# How to consolidate cases in a switch statement?

Tags: java, switch-statement, program-flow

In a program I am currently working on, I am utilizing a switch statement with many cases yielding the same result. The relevant bit of my current code looks like this:

```
int[] vinArray = new int[17];
    for(int x=0;x<17;x++)
    {
        v = vinString.substring(x,x+1);

        switch(v)
        {
            case "A": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "B": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "C": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "D": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "E": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "F": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "G": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "H": vinArray[x]=1; break;
            case "J": vinArray[x]=2; break;
            case "K": vinArray[x]=2; break;
            case "L": vinArray[x]=2; break;
            case "M": vinArray[x]=2; break;
            case "N": vinArray[x]=2; break;

        }
}
```

I was wondering if their is a way to consolidate the cases that perform the action is a manner like this (psuedo-code):

```
case "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H": vinArray[x]=1; break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply omit the break between cases to fall through:

```
case "A":
case "B":
case "C": // etc
  vinArray[x] = 1;
  break;
case "J":
case "K": // etc
  vinArray[x] = 2;
  break;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be accomplished like this:

```
case "A": 
case "B": 
case "C": 
case "D": 
    vinArray[x]=1; 
    break;
```

Also, be careful, you are missing some ; in your statements.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I'm sure others are working on that, but in this case I think a better solution would be

```
char v = vinString.charAt(x);
if (v >= 'A' && v <= 'H') {
    vinArray[x]=1;
} else if (v >= 'J' && v <= 'N') {
    vinArray[x]=2;
}
```